# Hi , i am new to c++. i want to know what is this means?

Tags: c++

Can somebody tell me how this statement work. As i can understand two integers are defined as `besti` and `bestSAD`. `bestSAD` value depends upon the condition `(last ==-1)` , if true it is equal to `MAX_UINT` if not it is equal to `psList[last].getSAD(sElement)`. But result does not confirm this though.

```
int besti = last, bestSAD = (last == -1) ? 
     MAX_UINT : psList[last].getSAD(sElement);
```

Also what is the advantage of putting these in one statement?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show an example that fails. The benefit would be to not type `int` again, so considering the statement, I'd never put a ternary compounded with another like that.

Comment: Advantage is to have short code

Comment: This terse style of declaration with multiple variables declared and initialized on one line is more characteristic of C code than C++ where coding guidelines often specify one variable definition per line but some people prefer the space savings of this style over the arguably easier readability of the one variable per line style.

Comment: Please remove all the fluff from your post. That includes saluataton, apologies and other pleasantries. Next, try to make it an on-topic question. Take extra care that the title reflects your actual question. For requesting help finding an error, you need to supply a minimal complete verifiable example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the same as:

```
int besti;
int bestSAD;

besti = last;

if ( last == -1 )
    bestSAD = MAX_UINT;
else
    bestSAD = psList[last].getSAD(sElement);
```

`MAX_UINT` is not part of Standard C++, it may be something defined in a header file you haven't shown somewhere. If they meant UINT_MAX then this line causes implementation-defined behaviour (which the person who wrote this code may assume will generate `bestSAD == -1` although that is not guaranteed).